# In-app billing v3 - How to save user data/transaction correctly?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Please note that i am asking this question, in process of understanding a better way to implement and handle in-app billing in my application.

I just implemented in-app billing V3 successfully to my app. Now my question is, should i store the transaction details, in Database or on Server? If yes, why?

Let me explain my scenario a bit. In my app i have a premium upgrade, that users can buy to unlock certain features. Now, when a user purchases the upgrade, Google Play handles the transaction and lets me know whether the purchase was successful or not. So, if the purchase is successful, i will unlock the features for that user, and store in preferences, whether the purchase is successful or not.

When the application launches, i check(every time), whether the product is purchased or not, and update my application based on that. What happens if the device is not connected to internet? I will go with what the preferences have in currently.

What are the downsides of this approach? When will it fail? and how is storing data on Server help me in better implementation?

Comment: By 'what the preferences have in currently', do you mean the SharedPreferences provided by android or a method you have implemented?

Comment: I am thinking of extending SharedPreferences provided by android and encrypting the values whatever i store in them. Will that work?

Comment: The only problem with encrypting the values is that anyone who is able to reverse engineer your app is able to see how you are encrypting the values. This would allow them to decrypt the values or encrypt and save their own values. There is really no way around this other than checking the purchase every time the user is connected to a network.